# Passing a dynamic array to Morris Chart using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, morris.js

I need to graph a dynamic array using Morris Charts. The array is a dynamic rectangular array (with variable number of columns) that looks like this:

[image: Rectangular Array]

I tried passing it to Morris Charts using JSON. This is my code:

```js
 function SHOWGRAPH() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/samplepage.aspx/SHOW_GRAPH",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            
                 
              for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
              
                Morris.Area({ 
                     
                    element: 'myfirstchart',
                    data:data.d,
                    xkey: data.d[0],
                    ykeys: [data.d[i]],
                    hideHover: 'auto',
                    resize: true,                    
                     
                })
                };
               
            }

        });
    }
```

I am getting an error due to unmatched data set:

```
 TypeError: a is undefined
```

I would like to ask if anyone has an idea how to properly pass rectangular array to Morris Chart. Normally, I only use a class to pass data. However, in this instance, the structure of the data I need to pass is dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to be passing any data in the request body:

`data: "",`

Do you get the response fine? Maybe try and `console.log` the response to make sure data is being sent back.

Comment: hmmm. It's because the function SHOW_GRAPH() doesn't require a parameter.

Comment: Do you get the response fine? Maybe try and `console.log` the response to make sure data is being sent back. If `SHOW_GRAPH()` is a `POST` request handler that requires no body, then it should work fine, but either way, make sure there is data returned. It's kinda difficult to debug the snippet because there's no actual data there

Answer (score 2):

Here, you don't seem to be passing any data in the `POST` request body. If this does not require a request body, you should think of making it a `GET` request instead. Either way, if the response is in JSON format like so:

```
{ "data": {
    "d": {
        [ a: []],
        [ a: []],
        [ a: []],
        [ a: []],
        [ a: []]
        }
}
```

Then you should ideally be looping twice like so:

```
data.d.forEach(function(data) {
    Morris.Area({ 

                element: 'myfirstchart',
                data:data,
                xkey: data.a.forEach(function(item){
                           //Do what you want with this array
                        }),
                ykeys: [data],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                resize: true,                    

            })
            };
});
```